# How to send data from UItextfields of one viewcontroller to new view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass data from 2 UItextfields to new view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935280/pass-data-from-2-uitextfields-to-new-view-controller)

I am desining an application with two view controllers. I navigate to the second view contoller through a button and a function. I am not sure how to send data from this view controller to another. I want to display this data in the second view controller.